# Wordpress JSON API returns normal site page in html. How do I get it to give me JSON?

Tags: json, rest-api, plugin-json-api

For example, entering `http://mywordpresswebsite.example.com/?json=1` into the browser loads the main site html, the same as omitting the json querystring variable: `http://mywordpresswebsite.example.com/`

The JSON API is activated.  I have tried reactivating and deactivating, checking .htaccess file settings, and deactivating all other plugins.  None of those have made much difference so far.

Comment: what do you men "json api is activated". the api is part of version 4.7 and there is nothing that needs to be activated

Comment: Touche Mark.  But it still doesn't work when the old plugin is deactivated.

Comment: the end point is in `/wp-json`, have you tried it?

Comment: I didn't know that but it gave me a 404 error.

however, `/index.php/wp-json` worked.  Thank you!!

Comment: if you need the /index.php there is probably something generaly wrong with how permalinks are setup on the site. never saw it myself so not sure what advice to give

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the new endpoint for Wordpress 4.7 is mywordpresswebsite.example.com/index.php/wp-json. It's part of Wordpress Core as of 4.7 and not a plugin anymore, there's nothing to be activated. Thank you, Mark Kaplun.

Answer (score 1):

I'm likely doing it wrong, but when I form my requests for a Wordpress installation at `http://www.example.com/` like this:

`http://www.example.com/index.php?rest_route=/my/rest/route/here`

I end up getting proper responses back.

I had a heck of a time figuring this out and ended up grokking a URL formatted like that in the HTML returned to me. I was expecting to make requests as `http://www.example.com/wp_json/wp/v2/my/rest/route/here` , but I only got HTML responses.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it setting the permalink in the wordpress and also changing the .htaccess (see https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-posts-returning-404-error/) to make permalink work correctly.